# OSGI plugin access the file in the resources.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have to modify existing application to act as an OSGI plugin, I have stumbled on the following issue. This application depends on the `xml` file which is in the `jar` file, this application also loads this file during the runtime, and because of that in the OSGI environment it is not accessible. Any suggestion how I can fix this issue, so far I have tried following solution none have yield any positive results yet.

**This is how initially it was loaded**

```
InputStream templateInputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/template.xml");
```

**I tried to do it in the following way**

```
URL url = null;
try {
  url = new URL("file:/lib/resources.jar");
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
URL[] urls = {url};
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, DeclareMapFactory.class.getClassLoader());
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
InputStream templateInputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/template.xml");
```

**This was also an attempt**

```
InputStream templateInputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/template.xml");
```

Jar file is in the `lib` directory and is loaded via the `MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: Can you explain exactly where the xml file is located? Is it inside the bundle you deploy or in a separate resources.jar?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider, xml is located in the resources.jar file, which is located in the bundle's lib folder and referenced in manifest: `Bundle-ClassPath: lib/resources.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So lets assume template.xml is located at resources/template.xml in a jar resources.jar. This jar is inside your bundle and referenced using Bundle-ClassPath.

In this case the content of the resources jar should be added to the classpath of your bundle.

So when you are inside a class of the bundle you should be able to do:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/template.xml")
```

If that does not work then maybe you need to start the path with a "/" but  I think it should work without.

Comment: I prefer the code pattern `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/template.xml")`. Using the class-literal is safer than `this.getClass()` because if the class is ever subclassed in another bundle then `this` will not be the type you expect it to be, and the class loader (and therefore the visible resources) could be different.

Comment: Thanks guys the issue was with the path :)